# How to install Luajittex from binary

Tags: luatex, installing, luaotfload

(tagged `luaotfload` as its slowness is the main reason why I'm installing this!)

I have a "BIN" file called `luajittex` (literally that's it, no file extension or anything) which I downloaded to use for compiling instead of LuaTeX (it may compile faster, not sure yet).

I use Linux 17.1 and I placed `luajittex` in `/usr/bin`. I tried running `luajittex 1.tex` on a document (in the terminal) and it said that it couldn't find `luajittex.fmt` so obviously it did not install correctly!

Can someone please instruct me on how to install `luajittex` from [this raw luajittex file here](http://minimals.contextgarden.net/current/bin/luatex/linux-64/bin/)?

Comment: http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/linux-64/ [Don't know if it is helpful - worth a look.]

Comment: *(tagged luaotfload as its slowness is the main reason why I'm installing this!)* -- Have you thought this through? Luaotfload execution time is largely determined by file IO. Font parsing is done by the engine anyways so performance is not going to increase by adding the JIT. Btw. unless you’re from the future I doubt that you already use “Linux 17.1”.

Comment: Also, installing a binary from Context  won’t work if in
combination with TeX Live since a matching ``texmf.cnf``
must be present at compile time. Why don’t you just use
the Luajittex binary supplied with your TeX distribution?